# Display UIAlertView if my JSON does not load?

Tags: ios, error-handling, uialertview

Here is my question.  How do I display an error if my app is unable to load my remote JSON file?  I turned my wifi off on my computer and ran the app in the Simulator.  It NSLogs the message that should be displayed if there is connection.  How can I fix this? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *jsonStr = @"http://xxx.com/server.php?json=1";
    NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:jsonStr];
   // NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
   // NSError *jsonError = nil;
    NSURLRequest *jsonLoaded = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:jsonURL];

    if(!jsonLoaded) {

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
        alertView.title = @"Error!";
        alertView.message = @"A server with the specified hostname could not be found.\n\nPlease check your internet connection.";
        [alertView addButtonWithTitle:@"Ok"];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
        NSLog(@"No connection, JSON not loaded...");

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"JSON loaded and ready to process...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code just creates the request.  It doesn't actually fetch the data.  You need to use `NSURLConnection` to fetch the data.

There are multiple ways to fetch the data.  This example is for iOS 5.0 or higher:

```
NSOperationQueue *q = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
NSURLRequest *jsonRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:jsonURL];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:jsonRequest
                                   queue:q
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           // data was received
                           if (data)
                           {
                               NSLog(@"JSON loaded and ready to process...");
                               // ... process the data
                           }
                           // No data received
                           else
                           {
                               NSLog(@"No connection, JSON not loaded...");
                               // ... display your alert view
                           }
                       }];
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this now.  Whee do I insert this code?  Under the NSUrl?

Comment: This still doesn't work.  My json is at an external URL.  My wifi us off, and it still says that the json is loaded, when it can't possibly be.

Comment: Your code works now, but it just NSLogs... It doesn't show alertview.

Answer (score 0):

You have not actually requested anything yet. Read [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE) on how to make requests.

Basically, what you want to do is to implement [NSURLConnectionDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) protocol and override `connection:didFailWithError:` function to listen for failure event.